# AFP AD ACL permissions issues with external drive

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, access-control-list, afp

Mac OS X Server 10.4.11 connected to an AD domain system serving AFP shares to Mac OS X 10.5.8.

If I create a share on the the internal RAID of the server with an ACL that allows RW to all ("Domain Users"), then it works, but a share created identically on the external RAID appliance (Drobo v2) doesn't. When the share from the Drobo is mounted, it shows no sign that it has any ACLs associated with it: neither in the Finder (Get Info), nor when checked via the terminal with "ls -lae". The Drobo does show that the ACLs exist when I ssh into the server and check it there, but when the clients mount that share, they just... ...disappear.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What file system is on the drop disks?